# What's the difference between a string and an array of characters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

When I checked if these two were equal, they apparently weren't. Can someone explain why?

```
var string = "Hello";
var array = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];
```

Why is `(string === array)` is false ?

EDIT: This website is fantastic. Such fast help. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Why is `(string === array)` is false ?

You are using [strict comparison (`===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_when_to_use_them#Strict_equality_using_.3D.3D.3D), which also checks the **data type** of the values. Obviously a **primitive string** value is not the same data type as an **object**, and objects are only truly equal to themselves. Proof:

```
var foo = [1,2,3];
var bar = [1,2,3];

console.log(foo === bar); // false
console.log(foo === foo); // true
```

Now, if you were to use [**loose** comparison (`==`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_when_to_use_them#Loose_equality_using_.3D.3D), the following comparison does return `true`:

```
console.log([1,2,3] == '1,2,3'); // true
```

Why? Because the array is converted to a string first, and this happens to result in the same string value. But that doesn't mean that the values are the same (one is still an array and the other a string). That's why you should always use strict comparison.

---

> What's the difference between a string and an array of characters in Javascript?

Strings **are not** arrays because they are inheriting from [different](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype) [prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) (*) and hence have different instance methods. For example, arrays have a [method `join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and strings have a [method `match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

From one point of view, arrays and strings are *similar* though, because they are both *array-like* objects.

What does *array-like* mean? It means that the object has a `length` property and numeric properties. A string has a `length` property which gives you the number of characters in the string, and you can access single characters of the string with `str[i]`. Example:

```
var arr = ['a','b','c'];
var str = "abc";

console.log(arr.length); // 3
console.log(str.length); // 3

console.log(arr[0]); // a
console.log(str[0]); // a

console.log(arr === str); // false

console.log(typeof str); // string
console.log(typeof arr); // object
```

---

*: Actually, there even is a difference between primitive strings and String objects, but I don't want to go too deep here. Technically primitive strings don't have any methods because they are not objects, but in most cases, you can treat primitive strings like they were objects.

Answer (score 2):

You are confused with c/c++. In java-script array is another object and string variable is another one. Try reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals)

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript `===` is **strict equality** which compares two values for equality. Neither value is implicitly converted to some other value before being compared. So that's why you have to different objects (String and Array) which cannot be equal and that is why your comparison returns `false`.

More on that you can find on [Strict equality using ===](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_when_to_use_them)

Answer (score 2):

Although most of answers are correct I want to add few things on top of that.
I don't want to repeat, why comparison is false as other have explained it.

Here is one other difference in string and array with same content.

```
const str = 'Hello';
const arr = ['H','e','l','l','o'];
```

When we declare vairbale constant with reference data type we can manipulate content.

```
arr = anotherArray;
```

will give us error however still we can do

```
arr[0] = 'S';
```

array now will look like ['S','e','l','l','o'];

In case of string although you can access elements by array notation, if you try to
change its content it will fail silently i.e.  will not throw any error but will not change content either.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, String and Array data types are not equal.