# Is it okay to use for in loop on a string?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, indexof, for-in-loop, lastindexof

Just wondering if its acceptable to use a for in loop on a string. Not sure if there could be weird results or bad practice but my solution works at least in this example.

Coding practice question. Also, if anyone has a way to improve my solution I'm open to advice.

```
function firstNonRepeatingLetter(str) {
  const lowerStr = str.toLowerCase();

  for (let char in lowerStr) {
    if (lowerStr.lastIndexOf(lowerStr[char]) === parseInt(char) && 
    lowerStr.indexOf(lowerStr[char]) === parseInt(char)) {
      return str[char];
    }
  }

  return "";
}
```

Write a function named `first_non_repeating_letter` that takes a `string` input, and returns the first character that is not repeated anywhere in the string.

Examples:

```
firstNonRepeatingLetter('a') => 'a'
firstNonRepeatingLetter('stress') => 't'
firstNonRepeatingLetter('sTreSS') => 'T'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a string and an array of characters in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808687/whats-the-difference-between-a-string-and-an-array-of-characters-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your code is working, I suggest to take an index for iterating the characters of a string.

But your approach iterates the string to much by using `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`. This could be changed by using a loop storing the last found index of the character.

In another loop, compare the actual index with the stored one for the same character and return if equal.

```js
function firstNonRepeatingLetter(str) {
    var lowerStr = str.toLowerCase(),
        hash = {},
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < lowerStr.length; i++)
        hash[lowerStr[i]] = i;

    for (i = 0; i < lowerStr.length; i++)
        if (hash[lowerStr[i]] === i)
            return str[i];

    return "";
}

console.log(firstNonRepeatingLetter('a'));      // a
console.log(firstNonRepeatingLetter('stress')); // t
console.log(firstNonRepeatingLetter('sTreSS')); // T
```

Comment: you misspelled  `indesOf`

Comment: @Noob, you too.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, yes, you can use `for..in` with strings. The truth is, in most cases, you shouldn't.

`for(i in X)` works this way:

- if X is not an object, convert it to a respective wrapper (a number to a `Number`, a string to a `String`)
- for each "enumerable property" of X, assign its name to i and run the loop body

So strings are converted to `String` objects, and, as you can see in the console, they are just like arrays: they have numeric properties from 0 to length - 1 and each property contains the respective character:

[image]

That is, yes, the above logic works just fine with strings.

However, if you only want to iterate a string char-by-char, there's a more direct way to do the same: the `for..of` loop.

`for(a of X)` picks each *element* (not property) from X (which can be a string, an array or any "iterable" object) and assigns it to "a". With `for..of`, your code can be refactored like this:

```
function firstNonRepeatingLetter(str) {
    const lowerStr = str.toLowerCase();

    for (let char of lowerStr) {
        if (lowerStr.lastIndexOf(char) === lowerStr.indexOf(char))
            return char;
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: thanks!! I started using for of but since I wanted their indexes I decided to switch to for in. Appreciate your response!

Answer (score 1):

An algorithmic approach using `javascript maps`:
And yes, it's perfectly fine to use `for loops` with strings.

```js
const fn = (str) => {
  res = [];
  var ch = new Map();
  for(var i = 0; i<str.length; i++) {
    if(ch.has(str[i])) {
      var val = ch.get(str[i])
      val += 1
      ch.set(str[i],val)
    } else {
      ch.set(str[i], 1)
    }
  }
  ch.forEach((val, key) => {
    if(val == 1) {
      res.push(key)
    }
  })
  return res[0]
}

console.log(fn('abcdeabcdef'))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using two array ? Firstly, you can make an array using `split` and also create reversed array.

```
const origin = str.split('');
const reverse = [...origin].reverse();
```

Then, you can use `filter`.

```
const nonRepeats = origin.filter((ele, index) => ele !== reverse[index]);
return nonRepeats[0];
```

Comment: Awesome solution thanks! These are the kind of solutions I'm trying to work towards getting

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title, the `for..in` statement is intended for iterating enumerable object properties (including members in the prototype chain). While it *"works"* on iterable types, it is generally advised against using it as a method of iterating array-like structures as it can yield unexpected results when you are typically only looking at numerical indices.

For example, imagine you later polyfill functionality or otherwise modify the String prototype.

```js
String.prototype.polyfill = () => {}
for(const prop in 'abc')
    console.log(prop)
```

---

**Edit:** Oh snap. Looks like two of us got there at the same time. I'll also note then that regular expressions are good at solving this kind of problem. <sup>[regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/dQGdre/1)</sup>

```js
const firstNonRepeatingLetter = str => 
    (str && /(.)(?!.*?\1)/i.exec(str)[0]) || ''
    
;[
    'a',
    'stress',
    'sTreSS'
]
    .forEach(
        str => console.log(firstNonRepeatingLetter(str))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think once you resolve the answer on a website where you have found this task it will show you other answers, so you can see some other approaches.

Back to the question - you can convert string to array via `.split()` method. Array provides number of useful methods like `.filter()`, `.map()` etc. that can be used instead of `for` loop.